# How can I delete an image (AMI) in AWS EC2 using the SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I am using `CreateImage()` to create a new AMI from an existing Instance and I was hoping there was a `DeleteImage()` which would work in the converse fashion.  Unfortunately this method does not exist on the EC2Client.

What is the proper way to delete an AMI through the SDK using C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`DeregisterImage()`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_EC2_AmazonEC2Client_DeregisterImage.htm) that should do what you want. Note that it's up to you to delete any snapshots the image may be based upon afterward.

Comment: Quoting from http://www.newvem.com/amazon-aws-cloud-support/amazon-machine-image-ami-how-to-de-register-and-delete-amis/ -- "You need to delete your deregistered AMIs from Amazon S3. If you don’t then you will continue to be charged for the space you’re using". This was not mentioned in this [or any] answer. If I knew how to do that deletion -- you need to know the S3 storage location to do the deletion and finding that out is not trivial -- I would answer instead of just leaving this "but that's not a complete answer" comment.

Comment: @J.Merrill - from what I understand, "deleting" the deregistered AMI means that you delete the snapshot that was created when you registered the AMI.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick snippet:

```
AmazonEC2 ec2 = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonEC2Client();

DeregisterImageRequest deregisterImageRequest = new DeregisterImageRequest();
deregisterImageRequest.ImageId = AMIName;

DeregisterImageResponse deregisterImageResponse = new DeregisterImageResponse();
deregisterImageResponse = ec2.DeregisterImage(deregisterImageRequest);
```

Remember to handle exceptions and remove the snapshots..

However there is an issue with deleting the associated snapshots.

If you try to find out the blockdevice mapping using DescribeImageAttributeRequest an exception occurs - "Unauthorized attempt to access restricted resource" :

```
DescribeImageAttributeRequest describeImageAttributeRequest = new DescribeImageAttributeRequest().WithImageId("ami-name").WithAttribute("blockDeviceMapping");

DescribeImageAttributeResponse describeImageAttributeResponse = new DescribeImageAttributeResponse();

describeImageAttributeResponse = ec2.DescribeImageAttribute(describeImageAttributeRequest);
```

See post:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=231972